# Appium Android SendKey not working

Tags: appium, testdroid

I am trying to automate my android application test on testdroid server using Appium Java client. I am getting exception that unable to locate element while using element.sendKeys on AndroidElement.

```
AndroidElement element = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]"
               + "/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]"
               + "/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]"
               + "/android.widget.EditText[1]"));
element.click();
wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
element.sendKeys("Hello World");
```

In above code element.sendKeys throws exception

> An element could not be located

Looks like it is "hinted text issue" of sendKey but not sure.

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For android you should set capability "unicodeKeyboard" to "true". Also don't forget to reset

```
capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", "true");
```

Refer http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.3.4/?ruby#android-only

Comment: @dhiren : i'm using this capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "true");
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", "true"); 
But the problem in fields where i want to enter a value like price or quantity i got 11 instead of 1 in quantity or 2206 instead of 206 in price field this happen most of the time.

Comment: Is it happening on Mobile or emulator? because I tried "Hello World" and was not stripping "ll"?  what is texttype of price field?